# spawn UNKNOWN in grunt test

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-jasmine, spawn

Installed all karma and jasmine dependencies but getting following error while running grunt test

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
21 03 2017 18:07:33.233:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
21 03 2017 18:07:33.235:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
21 03 2017 18:07:33.252:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
Fatal error: spawn UNKNOWN
```

The following code from Karm.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      // Default Dependecies
      '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'spec/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you share karma.conf file?

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE, please refer karma.conf.js